# Calculating derivative (i.e. change in one variable based on change in another variable) of longitudinal dataset using R

Tags: r

I am dealing with a large dataset (~1 million obs) that includes time series data. In other words, my dataset includes multiple observations of a unique identifier (`id`) on a day-by-day basis (which, for the sake of providing a simple example, is just an integer value).  For example, my data might look like this:

```
id    var    day
1     49     1
1     51     2
1     53     3
1     50     4
2     45     1
2     46     2
2     45     3
2     44     4
```

Now, I'd like to calculate the derivative of `var` between successive days.  In other words, I'd like to calculate the change in `var` between day 1 and day 2, day 2 and day 3, etc. for each `id`. The resulting dataset would thus look like this:

```
id    var    day   deriv
1     49     1     NA
1     51     2     2
1     53     3     2
1     50     4     -3
2     45     1     NA
2     46     2     1
2     45     3     -1
2     44     4     -1
```

I suspect that there is some spectacularly simple solution using something like `melt` that I don't know about.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: `var` is a discrete variable. So, what, exactly, do you mean by "derivative"?

Comment: `derivative` meaning change in the variable based on change in time? If this is a confusing descriptor, I can just call it `delta_var`?

Comment: Let me be more clear: your variable isn't continuous, so I don't know what you mean by "derivative", since the smallest difference between any two values is 1.

Comment: OK -- what I want is delta_var, where delta_var is equal to var(at day+1) minus var(at day).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
> dfrm$deriv <- ave(dfrm$var, dfrm$id, FUN=function(v) c(NA, diff(v)) )
> dfrm
  id var day deriv
1  1  49   1    NA
2  1  51   2     2
3  1  53   3     2
4  1  50   4    -3
5  2  45   1    NA
6  2  46   2     1
7  2  45   3    -1
8  2  44   4    -1
```

Answer (score 0):

If `d` is the matrix and the `day` variable is ordered, try this:

`do.call("c",lapply(unique(d[,1]),function(x){y <- d[d[,1]==x,];z <- y[2:nrow(y),]-y[1:(nrow(y)-1),]; c(NA,z[,2]/z[,3])}))`

This would give you a vector corresponding to `delta_var`

Comment: check out the diff() function, it will make your life easier!